# numpy imported successfully on command line but not on IDLE

Tags: macos, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I can import numpy successfully using my python version 2.7.11 on the command line :  [image]

but not in IDLE where I get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macbookpro/Desktop/Python learning/Mortgages/mortgage_plot.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pylab
  File "/Users/macbookpro/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "/Users/macbookpro/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 124, in <module>
    from . import cbook
  File "/Users/macbookpro/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

[image]

What could be the source of this problem ?

Comment: Your `IDLE` runs on a different python environment which does not have `numpy` installed. While the default Python that you start with command line has it.

Comment: @swatchai how do you know that ?

Comment: Look at the Python versions

Answer (score 2):

A possible candidate for this error can be that the `numpy` package is not present in the directories where your IDLE searches for the package.

However the package is available for your command line python package path. Try adding the package location to your IDLE's package search path. I think that should resolve this error.

You can add following lines at top to add package path ( for this program only ) to use `numpy` :

```
import sys
sys.path 
sys.path.append('path/to/package/numpy')
import numpy
```

Answer (score 1):

Download numpy package from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy .
Or you can also work on anaconda